# How to iterate through a double linked list and create a new list to a specific value?

Tags: java, generics, doubly-linked-list

How iterate through a double-linked list and create a new double linked list below or equal or above or equal a specific value?

For example:

```
["A", "B", "C"].below("B") = ["A", "B"]
```

I got a ClassCastException, so I don't know how to implement create a new list and add those nodes till the specific value. I have already implemented my own compareto method which works right. My add method also works right.

```
main class:
.
.//some code
    LinkedList<Item> itemList = new LinkedList<>();
    itemList.add(....(..)));
    .//some code
    print(itemList.below(new Drink("Cola", 1.0, 1.0)));
    .
    .//some code

    public class LinkedList <T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements List<T>
    {
    ..

     private Node <T> head;
     private Node <T> last;
    ..//some code
    public void add(T value)
        { ..}

    public LinkedList <T> below (T value)
        {
            LinkedList <T> b = new LinkedList<>();
            Node <T> curr = new Node<>(value);
            Node <T> start = this.head;

            while(start.next != null && curr.data.compareTo(start.next.data) <= 0 )
            {
                b.add((T) start); //ClassCastException
                start = start.next;
            }
            return b;
        }


 private static class Node <T>
   {

    private T data;
    private Node <T> next;
    private Node <T> prev;
    private static int counter = 0;
    private final int ID;

    private Node(T data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.ID = counter;
        counter++;

    }

   }
 }
```

Comment: `start` is defined to be a `Node<T>`.  Why do you think you can cast it to a `T`?  Did you mean `start.data`?  Need a [mcve].

Comment: because head is also a Node<T>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ClassCastException` is because `start` is defined to be a `Node<T>` and the following code casts a `Node<T>` object to a `T` object, which is a runtime error.

```
b.add((T) start); //ClassCastException
```

You probably mean to call:

```
b.add(start.data)
```

However, `data` is marked `private`.  So either mark it `public`, or better, add an accessor `getData()` method in `Node`.

Comment: thank you it's working correct now but I didn't really need to use getData() since my Note class is a private nested class.